# get token balance from another contract

Tags: smart-contract, tokens, balances

How do we accomplish this on EOSIO?

In Ethereum we get the reference of another contract using the contract address, what about for EOSIO?

Can anyone provide a sample code for this?

Would like to pull the balance from another smart contract.

Answer (score 8):

Declare the following struct in your contract

```
struct account {
        asset    balance;
        uint64_t primary_key()const { return balance.symbol.name(); }
     };

typedef eosio::multi_index<N(accounts), account> accounts;
```

Write the following in one of the action of contract. It is reading the accounts table of eosio.token contract and printing the balance of "user111"

```
symbol_type symbol(S(4,SYS));
accounts fromAcc(N(eosio.token),N(user111));
const auto& myAcc = fromAcc.get(symbol.name());
myAcc.balance.print();
```

Comment: thanks for the information, I also assume that the contract file of eosio.token.hpp should be included in the contract where I'm calling it right?

Comment: You can use it without including eosio.token.hpp, In that case you have to copy "struct account" and its multi_index table type  as shown in the above answer to your contract file

Comment: So if you `#include <eosiolib/eosio.token.hpp>` you can just use that last section of your post, without `struct account...` and `typedef eosio::multi_index...`? Cheers, good answer

Comment: When I try this, I get the error: `unable to find key`

Answer (score 0):

By querying eosio.token's `accounts` table.

`./cleos/cleos -u http://api.eosnewyork.io:80 get table eosio.token <account-name> accounts`

BTW, this returns `[]` if the account is never transferred any token (like EOS).

Use `userres` table to get account info.

`./cleos/cleos -u http://api.eosnewyork.io:80 get table eosio <account-name> userres`

Comment: Yeah, but how do we translate it or write it inside of another smart contract? Any idea?

Comment: @Dominic I don't know how to access table data of other contracts from one contract. But a workaround could be moving this logic from contract to app. In other word, contract logic only does simple work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the logic requires to get the balance directly from another contract.