# In the eosio.token contract, why are the structs private?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, eosio.token, contract-development

In my contract, I'd like to be able to check how much EOS an account has.
For that, I'd write some C++ code like this:

```
token::accounts the_table("eosio.token"_n, "useraccount1"_n.value);
auto it = the_table.begin();
auto how_much = it -> balance;
```

Here, I'd use the type `token::accounts` from the `eosio.token` [contract](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/8b0d3fd/eosio.token/include/eosio.token/eosio.token.hpp#L75).

The problem is that, in the official `eosio.token` contract, this type is private, so my code above does not compile.
So, instead of just an `#include ".../eosio.token.hpp"`, now I copy the type declaration to the code of my contract, like this:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] account {
    asset balance;
    uint64_t primary_key() const {return balance.symbol.code().raw();}
};

typedef eosio::multi_index <"accounts"_n, account> accounts;
```

Copying and modifying the data structures, just to be able to access them, is bad coding practice.
But maybe I'm using a wrong approach here.
So my question here is two-fold:

1. Why are the types in the official code private?
2. How to better see from within a contract how much EOS an account has?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get token balance from another contract](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1384/get-token-balance-from-another-contract)

Comment: @AmiHeines Thanks for the link! It's related, and one of the answer contains the premise of my question. Still, my question is about a particular shortcoming of that answer, which is not and should not be addressed there.

Comment: Perhaps the eosio.token contract needs to be changed and the struct should be moved to the public section of the class. Try raising an issue in the github repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contract rightfully encapsulates the implementation details as private.

Instead, it [provides](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/8b0d3fd/eosio.token/include/eosio.token/eosio.token.hpp#L53) the following function as the public interface:

```
static asset get_balance( name token_contract_account, name owner, symbol_code sym_code )
```

A better version of the code to get EOS balance is thus as follows:

```
auto how_much = token::get_balance("eosio.token"_n, "useraccount1"_n, symbol_code("EOS"));
```

The problem was that I didn't notice the function on my first read.